# Mocking iterative behaviour

Tags: c#, unit-testing, tdd, mocking, rhino-mocks

I have an interface with iterative behaviour, and I am having trouble Mocking that in Rhinomocks. The example interface and class is a very simple version of my problem.

Every time LineReader.Read() is called, the LineReader.CurrentLine() should return a different value -- the next line. This behaviour I haven't been able to reproduce in a mock so far. Thus, it has become a small hobby project of mine which I return to from time to time. I hope you can help me a step further.

```
internal class LineReader : ILineReader
{
    private readonly IList<string> _lines;
    private int _countOfLines;
    private int _place; 

    public LineReader(IList<string> lines)
    {
        _lines = lines;
        _countOfLines = lines.Count;
        _place = 0; 
    }

    public string CurrentLine()
    {
        if (_place<_countOfLines)
        {
            return _lines[_place];
        }
        else
        {
            return null; 
        }

    }

    public bool ReadLine()
    {
        _place++;
        return (_place < _countOfLines);
    }

}
```

**EDIT Incomplete unit test added**:

```
    [Test]
    public void Test()
    {
        IList<string> lineListForMock = new List<string>()
                                            {
                                                "A",
                                                "B",
                                                "C"
                                            };

        MockRepository mockRepository = new MockRepository();
        ILineReader lineReader = mockRepository.Stub<ILineReader>();

        //Setup the values here

        mockRepository.ReplayAll();

        bool read1 = lineReader.ReadLine();
        Assert.That(read1, Is.True);
        Assert.That(lineReader.CurrentLine(), Is.EqualTo("A"));

        bool read2 = lineReader.ReadLine();
        Assert.That(read2, Is.True);
        Assert.That(lineReader.CurrentLine(), Is.EqualTo("B"));

        bool read3 = lineReader.ReadLine();
        Assert.That(read3, Is.True);
        Assert.That(lineReader.CurrentLine(), Is.EqualTo("C"));

        bool read1 = lineReader.ReadLine();
        Assert.That(read1, Is.False);


    }
```

Comment: Did you start some code for your unit test ?

Comment: @Thomas, Give me two minutes :o)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is all you need:

```
var enumerator = new List<string> { "A", "B", "C" }.GetEnumerator();
var lineReader = MockRepository.GenerateStub<ILineReader>();

lineReader.Stub(x => x.CurrentLine())
    .Return("ignored")
    .WhenCalled(x => x.ReturnValue = enumerator.Current);

lineReader.Stub(x => x.ReadLine())
    .Return(false) // will be ignored
    .WhenCalled(x => x.ReturnValue = enumerator.MoveNext());
```

Comment: That is awesome... Gotta try it !! Thanks

Answer (score 2):

This seems to do the trick:

```
[TestFixture]
public sealed class TestIterativeRhinoReturn
{
    private int _count;
    private int _countOfLines; 
    private IList<string> _lines;
    private string _currentLine; 
    [SetUp]
    public void SetUp()
    {
        _count = -1;

        _lines= new List<string>()
                                            {
                                                "A",
                                                "B",
                                                "C",
                                                null
                                            };


        _countOfLines = _lines.Count;
        _currentLine = null; 
    }


    [Test]
    public void Test()
    {

        MockRepository mockRepository = new MockRepository();
        ILineReader lineReader = mockRepository.DynamicMock<ILineReader>();

        lineReader.Stub(r => r.ReadLine()).Callback(new ReadLineDelegate(ReadRecord)).Return(_count < _countOfLines);
        lineReader.Stub(r => r.CurrentLine()).Do(new CurrentStringDelegate(ReturnString)).Return(_currentLine);

        mockRepository.ReplayAll();

        bool read1 = lineReader.ReadLine();
        Assert.That(read1, Is.True);
        Assert.That(lineReader.CurrentLine(), Is.EqualTo("A"));

        bool read2 = lineReader.ReadLine();
        Assert.That(read2, Is.True);
        Assert.That(lineReader.CurrentLine(), Is.EqualTo("B"));

        bool read3 = lineReader.ReadLine();
        Assert.That(read3, Is.True);
        Assert.That(lineReader.CurrentLine(), Is.EqualTo("C"));

        bool read4 = lineReader.ReadLine();
        Assert.That(read4, Is.False);
        Assert.That(lineReader.CurrentLine(), Is.Null);


    }


    public delegate bool ReadLineDelegate();

    private bool ReadRecord()
    {
        _count++;
        return (_lines[_count]!=null);
    }

    public delegate string CurrentStringDelegate(); 

    private string ReturnString()
    {
        return _lines[_count]; 
    }
```

Notice the Lines:

```
        lineReader.Stub(r => r.ReadLine()).Callback(new ReadLineDelegate(ReadRecord)).Return(_count < _countOfLines);
        lineReader.Stub(r => r.CurrentLine()).Do(new CurrentStringDelegate(ReturnString)).Return(_currentLine);
```

and the Delegate methods ReadRecord() and ReturnString(). Now the returnvalue changes for each read.

Comment: Yes you need to simulate this using custom callbacks - the Do and the Callback take delegates. The value returned by the delegate would be the value returned by the mock when it is called. More info - http://goo.gl/77xrc Item#7. You can even access the argument values in each call to determine the result.

Comment: @Gishu, I'm glad I finally found out how to do it. However, this leaves me with the impression, that mocking this behaviour will often be much easier using an oldfashioned handmade dummy implementation of the interface instead of Rhinomocks.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if I have the latest version of rhino-mocks but my .Return method does not take a delegate / action --- something that may have been useful for doing what you want.

However, you seem to be closer to state-based testing here so maybe just create your own mock implementation for testing (or stub, or fake --- you choose :)

Then you can control the exact values you are after.

Comment: Will using DynamicMock<ILineReader> change anything?

Comment: The `Return` method appears to have the same signature, so no :(

Comment: See my own solution below. However, this will be very complicated to do in many situations. Often it will be much easier to create my own mock implementation -- just as you suggest.

Comment: It sounds like you are looking for the `WhenCalled` extension method. See my answer for an example.